# Will a stair skirt on only one side look weird?

Tags: skirting

I have some roughed in stairs with 2 landings that have 1 and 2 more steps to go 180 down into the basement. On the inside I have puck lights (already rocked) so I can't put a skirt there but on the other side one could work, and if it did, the skirt would hit the yet to be installed baseboard around the landing and look fine. Has anyone had a project like this? Is there a rule like no single skirts, lol? [image]
Thanks for your time.

Comment: This seems to be an aesthetic issue and I am not sure that we can be of much help.

Comment: a stair skirt on just one side would be absolutely fine

Comment: the skirt is purely for cosmetic decorative purpose thus do what pleases your eyes. You always install one, see how it look, and decide on the second later.

Comment: Thanks for your responses and yes, it is decorative and I'm really stuck with doing it on one side since the puck lights can't be disconnected without cutting the wires allowing the flange to cover the hole.